# Coordinate Geometry finding x and y

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

How would I rearrange this equation to find $x_3$ and $y_3$

$$\tan\ \alpha =\frac{\sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2}}{ \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}}$$

EDIT: So basically what I want to do is that I have two points x1y1 and x2y2. I can draw a line between these points, I want to shift/rotate the line by angle $\alpha$ using x1y1 as origin of rotation and then find the point on the end of the rotated line (x3y3).

This is for some angle corrections in a programming challenge where I have to operate a vehicle

Comment: this is only one equation so you cannot explicitly find values for two variables.

Comment: Is it possible to find x3+y3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\tan\alpha$, since everything in it is constant. Then your equation becomes:
$$(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2 = R^2$$
I.e., it is the equation of a circle with center $(x_2, y_2)$ of radius $R$. The sum $x_3+y_3$ is not constant on that circle, so no, you cannot solve for a particular value for it. The best you can say is that $$x_2+y_2 - R\sqrt 2 \le x_3+ y_3 \le x_2+y_2 + R\sqrt 2$$ but every value inbetween is taken on by some point on the circle.

**Edit:** for your actual problem, this just applying the rotation matrix for the angle $\alpha$ to the vector $(x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1)$, then adding $(x_1, y_1)$ back in again:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\y_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha &-\sin \alpha\\\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_2 - x_1\\y_2 - y_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix}$$ (for a counter-clockwise rotation when $\alpha > 0$).

Comment: Can you propose a solution from the extra information I provided?

Comment: @bi0phaz3 - I've added it. It's a straight-forward rotation.

Comment: If a is a negative angle will it rotate it clockwise?

Comment: is it cos a * sin a & -sin a * cos a or is it a 2x2 matrix

Comment: Shouldn't the -sin be on the 2nd column and 1st row of the rotational matrix

Comment: @bi0phaz3 - you are right (and obviously you did figure out it is a matrix). One has use different signs when tranforming vectors vs transforming coordinates, and though I tried to check it when I wrote the post, I still got it backward. But a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation of (0,1) should be (-1, 0), which requires the top right sine to be the negative. I've fixed it.

Comment: Hmm... The coordinate grid in the programming problem I'm doing indexes the coordinate grid in matrix convention, so x increases as you go to the right, and y increases when you go down instead of up, so it doesn't work quite as I want it to, do you have any suggestions on how to modify the rotational matrix to work with the coordinate grid

Comment: Flip the sign of the sines again! For this situation $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha &\sin \alpha\\-\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{bmatrix}$$ is the rotation matrix you need. The rest shouldn't change.

Comment: The rotations seems to be a bit off http://puu.sh/nuqJk/e857cda02d.jpg, that looks more like a correction of 0 no (Angle correction is relative to the imaginary line between my pod (The yellow one closest to '0'))? It works sometimes but for some angles it doesn't work, why?