# How to rotate a line segment around one of the end points?

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, rotations, angle

[image]

I am given x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub> and θ. How can I find x<sub>3</sub> and y<sub>3</sub>?

By the way, there can be another line segment on the other side of AB (as if the line was rotated counter-clockwise). How to find that too?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1678031/265466 for the solution

Comment: @amd That's nice. But a simpler explanation would be better.

Comment: I don’t see how it could be much simpler than the last part of the linked answer: translate to the origin, rotate, and translate back.

Comment: @amd I understand, and I actually used the process to solve my problem. But I was wondering if there is any direct geometric way instead of the 3 step translate->rotate->translate.

Comment: If you’re looking for a geometric construction, it comes down to being able to construct the angle $\theta$.You can build a circle with $A$ as its center and $AB$ a radius, then measure off the angle somehow and find the corresponding point on the circle.  It looks like the OP in the question I linked to was trying to do just that. If you’re doing this analytically, it’s equivalent to translate-rotate-translate, but a lot more work.

Comment: @amd I see. Okay. Can you post the last formula in the other post as an answer to this post so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward way to do this is to translate the point you’re rotating around to the origin, rotate, and then translate back. This yields the formula $$
\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\y_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_2-x_1\\y_2-y_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix}.
$$ Note that positive angles are conventionally taken to be *counterclockwise*, so if you want a clockwise rotation, either negate the angle or flip the signs of the sines in the rotation matrix.

If you use homogeneous coordinates, you can combine this into a single matrix multiplication:$$\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&-x_1\cos\theta+y_1\sin\theta+x_1 \\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta&-x_1\sin\theta-y_1\cos\theta+y_1 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Handy for combining with other transformations, but not really any less work. If you’re rotating several points at the same time, this form points out the common factors that you can precompute for all of those rotations.

Comment: Great  answer. But can you provide a link on an explanation describing how you obtain the 3 x 3 matrix transformation which can be directly applied to the B vector ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a short answer from @amd answer.

$x_3 = \cos (\theta)\space(x_2 - x_1) - \sin (\theta)\space(y_2 - y1)+ x_1$

$y_3 = \sin (\theta)\space(x_2 - x_1) + \cos (\theta)\space(y_2 - y1)+ y_1$